# Flutter - How to make a custom widget that adds a footer to a received scrollable widget?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-widget

I'm creating a custom widget that adds a footer as last item to any scrollable widget received.

The ideal use would be like this:

```
ScrollableWithFooter(
    child: ListView.builder(...),
    footer: Text('Footer'),
)

ScrollableWithFooter(
    child: GridView.builder(...),
    footer: Text('Footer'),
)

ScrollableWithFooter(
    child: CustomListView.builder(...),
    footer: Text('Footer'),
)

ScrollableWithFooter(
    child: SingleChildScrollView.builder(...),
    footer: Text('Footer'),
)

ScrollableWithFooter(
    child: StaggeredGridView.builder(...),
    footer: Text('Footer'),
)
```

This is the approach I'm taking:

```
class ScrollableWithFooter extends StatefulWidget {
  final ScrollView child;
  final Widget footer;

  ScrollableWithFooter({Key key, this.child, this.footer}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => ScrollableWithFooterState();
}

class ScrollableWithFooterState extends State<ScrollableWithFooter> {
  final _scrollController = ScrollController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      controller: _scrollController,
      scrollDirection: widget.child.scrollDirection,
      itemCount: 2,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        if (index == 0) {
          return widget.child;
        }
        return widget.footer;
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Note that it has a `ScrollController`, because I'll need to know if the footer is visible for other features.

**Problems**

- The `widget.child` has to wrap its content, otherwise:
  `Vertical viewport was given unbounded height`. I tried wrapping `widget.child` with `Wrap` or `IntrinsicHeight` but it doesn't work. The only thing I could do is make an `assert` if `widget.child` doesn't have `shrinkWrap: true`.
- The `widget.child` doesn't have to scroll, otherwise the custom widget won't scroll because `widget.child` is wrapped with a `ListView`. I tried wrapping `widget.child` with `IgnorePointer` or `GestureDetector` but I won't be able to tap on the items. The only thing I could do is make an `assert` if the `widget.child` `phyisics` aren't `NeverScrollableScrollPhysics`.
- If `widget.child` has a `controller`, since `widget.child` shouldn't be scrollable, I have to pass that `controller` to the parent `ListView` but I would get: `ScrollController attached to multiple scroll views`. The only thing I could do is allow the custom widget to receive a `controller` and make an `assert` if `widget.child` has a `controller`.

**Questions**

- How can I solve these problems?
- Is this a good approach?
- What other approaches could I take?

Comment: do you want to add Footer so it will looks like last item of list view or it should be a real footer at the bottom of container?

Comment: It should be the last item

Comment: look at this https://github.com/showang/flutter_easy_listview, I think you can dig into his code on GitHub, here is not so much code

Comment: Thanks, but that works only as ListView, I need to make a custom widget that works for any type of ScrollView, like GridView, StaggeredGridView, etc. If I take an approach similar to that link, I would need to make a lot of custom widgets one for each type of ScrollView and pass all the properties of each type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the `ScrollView` class I found a solution for this:

In the custom widget, instead of using the `widget.child` received I have to create a new `Scrollable` widget, doing this:

- The `Scrollable` will have `NeverScrollableScrollPhysics`
- The `Scrollable` won't have a `controller`
- The `Scrollable` will return a `ShrinkWrappingViewport` with the
  `axisDirection` and `slivers` from `widget.child`

Here is the implementation of the custom widget:

```
var _scrollController = ScrollController();

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _scrollController = widget.child.controller ?? _scrollController;
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return ListView.builder(
    controller: widget.child.controller,
    scrollDirection: widget.child.scrollDirection,
    itemCount: 2,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      if (index == 0) {
        return Scrollable(
          physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          axisDirection: widget.child.getDirection(context),
          viewportBuilder: (context, offset) {
            return ShrinkWrappingViewport(
              axisDirection: widget.child.getDirection(context),
              offset: offset,
              slivers: widget.child.buildSlivers(context),
            );
          },
        );
      }
      return widget.footer;
    },
  );
}
```

---

**Edit:** Here is a simplified alternative:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scrollable(
    controller: widget.child.controller,
    axisDirection: widget.child.getDirection(context),
    viewportBuilder: (context, offset) {
      return ShrinkWrappingViewport(
        axisDirection: widget.child.getDirection(context),
        offset: offset,
        slivers: widget.child.buildSlivers(context)
          ..add(SliverList(delegate: SliverChildListDelegate([widget.footer]))),
      );
    },
  );
}
```

---

And here are some examples of how to use it:

```
final _scrollController = ScrollController();

// ListView
ScrollableWithFooter(
  child: ListView.builder(
    controller: _scrollController,
    itemCount: 50,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) => Text('Item $index'),
  ),
  footer: Center(child: Text('Footer')),
)

// GridView
ScrollableWithFooter(
  child: GridView.builder(
    controller: _scrollController,
    itemCount: 50,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) => Text('Item $index'),
    gridDelegate:
        SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2),
  ),
  footer: Center(child: Text('Footer')),
)
```

Let me know if someone thinks this isn't good and has a better approach.